# Adding .ts extension to react-create-script

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a project setup with create-react-script and TypeScript enabled. In development mode I can easily import .ts scripts but when I build for production it weirdly keeps the .ts scripts intact.

Do I need to add .ts a babel override or something?

This is the output from running index.html of the build output:

[image]

Comment: Why did you conclude that .ts were left intact? There would be SyntaxError if this were so. This looks like some runtime error that is not TS issue and needs to be debugged on your end. That the log is minified doesn’t help.

Comment: I thought the above clearly identified the issue. If you click into errors.ts of Framer.tsx it displays the TS associated code for it. Is that not the case? Also I don't see any reason this would be a runtime issue, the identified error above is referencing the runtime failing over the basic basic declaration (a new class statement).

Comment: Am I to believe that create-react-app's default production output includes a source map or the uncompiled .ts? Even then it seems like it' strying to run the TS version and stumbling on it.

Comment: *Am I to believe that create-react-app's default production output includes a source map or the uncompiled .ts?* - that's correct. *Is that not the case?* - no, this means that source maps work like they should. Again, these errors would be impossible if TS weren't compiled, the only error you could get is **SyntaxError** because it wouldn't be valid JS.Since there's no SyntaxError, it's transpiled ok. That you don't see a reason for these errors means that you need to debug to find one. It could be anything. It's impossible to help with this problem without https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Consider debugging with real debugger in a console instead of index.html, the latter cannot fully make use of source maps and doesn't make the task easier.

Comment: Understood. I'll go digging. Sorry for the confusion, I expected source maps to be OFF by default. Thanks for the guidance ;-)